# Send data from file .cs or value of cshtml file to js MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a question.
Ex : I have student.cs  , student.cshtml .
I need get data of student.cs or student.cshtml to control.js 
in MVC.
how to do that?

Comment: How ask question on StackOverflow? Follow this link  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking how to get data from either the View (student.cshtml) or Controller (student.cs (should be named StudentController.cs)) to a JavaScript file (control.js) to manipulate it in Javascript.

The way I've done this is through the View using a hidden div.  Here is a generic example:

View:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="uniqueDivIdName" data-id="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model)" />
<script src="~/Scripts/control.js "></script>
```

Javascript:

```
var dataFromView = $("#uniqueDivIdName").data("id");
```