# Move Index.cshtml JavaScript array into separate script file

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, razor

I'm want to tidy my cshtml and move all my scripts in to separate JavaScript file but I have a problem with the following code, that combines C# loop and JavaScript array push:

```
var property = [];
var propertyCount = [];

@{

foreach(var property in Model.AllProperty)
{                     
        @:property.push("@property.Property");
        @:propertyCount.push("@property.Count");        
}

}
```

This a part of code is used with chart.js to create a pie chart.

How can I move this to JavaScript?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: reading this articles I can agree with one - I'm a n00b. 3 months as an apprentice, that's my experience. I think the question is fairly clear, this foreach loop combines c# and JavaScript, and that creates a problem when I want to split scripts from cshtml

Comment: Personally, I do think you cannot run Razor script inside pure JS files. Probably you have to pass them somehow in JS from the CSHTML file to the JS file. Not worth it, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this before.  Here's a generic solution to get the model data to Javascript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015471/11660681